# Encoded &quot; treated as a real double quote in Javascript onclick event - why?

Tags: javascript, encoding, xss

I noticed some behavior that I'm having a hard time understanding. Consider the following code snippet:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="window.location.href = &quot;foo;bar;&quot;">
```

When I click the test button it redirects the page to http://www.example.com/foo;bar;. So everything between the &quot; characters is being treated as a string literal, as if the &quot; were real quote characters. My expectation would be that since the &quot; characters are encoded they wouldn't be able to influence the code execution, so I'd expect the semicolon between foo and bar to terminate the assignment to window.location.href and for javascript to see bar as a separate statement.

Just to further confirm that that's what's happening, if I delete the first &quot; and click the button I get the following error in the console:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
>
> window.location.href = foo;bar;"

(with an arrow indicating the trailing ", which is really a &quot;, is the issue.)

What am I missing? Is the encoded character being decoded by the javascript engine before executing it? What if this involes user input, and the application tries encoding quote characters as &quot; to prevent cross-site scripting, will an attacker still be able to break out because his &quot; will still be honored as a real quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be getting your parsing order reversed.

The HTML parser converts the value of the attribute to text (so `&quot;` becomes `"`). That text is **then** passed to the JavaScript engine.

So what you have is fine and works as it should do.

---

> Is the encoded character being decoded by the javascript engine before executing it?

No, it is decoded by HTML parser before the JavaScript engine even gets to see it.

> What if this involves user input, and the application tries encoding quote characters as " to prevent cross-site scripting, will an attacker still be able to break out because his " will still be honoured as a real quote?

Assuming that you mean user input gets taken by the server, run through a standard HTML encoding routine to make it safe for inserting into HTML, and then inserted into the HTML:

If the user types `&quot;` then the server side application will encode it as `&amp;quot;`, and the HTML parser will decode it back to `&quot;` and not `"`.

Of course, if you are inserting user input into JavaScript (even if that JavaScript is also inside an HTML attribute) then you would need to escape it for JS before escaping it for HTML.

For example, using PHP as it is common:

```
<?php
$unsafe_input = $_GET['data'];
$js_safe_input = json_encode($unsafe_input);
$html_safe_input = htmlspecialchars($js_safe_input);
?>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(<?php echo $html_safe_input; ?>)" value="click">
```

Comment: Indeed it does work, I'm just trying to understand why. I thought converting quotes in user input to &quot; was the way to protect against cross-site scripting, but if they're all getting converted to " before being executed by the Javascript engine that seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: @jgor — That is how you make data safe for inserting into HTML, so the attacker can't switch the browser to parsing JavaScript (e.g. by ending the attribute value you are starting with a `"` and then creating a new onclick attribute). If you are inserting into JavaScript then you have to protect the JavaScript from malicious input as well as the HTML. See the example I added to the answer.

Comment: `If the user types &quot; then the server side application will encode it as &amp;quot;, and the HTML parser will decode it back to &quot; and not "` -- what if the user inputs ", wouldn't it be encoded to &quot; and then decoded back to " and executed?

Comment: thanks, I think I see my confusion now. You're saying if user input is being put into a Javascript block it is necessary to escape the quote (with backslash or similar) in addition to encoding it, knowing that it will be decoded before being passed to the Javascript engine.

Comment: Yes. Encoding as JSON is generally a safe way to do that (at least if you do it the way PHP does it, some other encoders might need a little extra work)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use escaped quotes instead

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="window.location.href = "\"foo;bar\"">
```

or use single quotes too

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="window.location.href = 'foo;bar;'">
```

Comment: Your attribute now reads: `onclick="window.location.href = "`

Comment: Sorry, I'm curious why the original code behaves the way it does. I'd like to understand whatever quirk it is that leads to that behavior, not correct it.